# Deploying Rails app to shared hosting service gives permission error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, hosting, shared-hosting

I'm trying to deploy a Rails 3.2.3 application to a shared hosting service (1and1) with Postgres as my database. I uploaded my folder to the website directory through FTP and pointed the domain to my rails folder in the control panel but when I go to the website homepage, I get "You don't have permission to access / on this server." I tried using Passenger but I'm not sure if that is needed or if it worked at all. I'm pretty new at this so step by step instructions would be great.

I'm using Mac OSX Snow Leopard, let me know if any more info is needed. Any more background articles to read would also be appreciated, I've been looking to find something that gives a good explanation of how this works but I have yet to find a good one.

Comment: Deploying a Rails application isn't as cut and dry as you are making out to be here. When you say shared hosting do you mean VPS or something using CPanel? What web server do you plan to use (usually Apache or Nginex)? Do you have shell access? 

You will create a symbolic link from your web root to the public/ folder within your app directory, making sure the directory permissions are set. If this is a VPS I would suggest following the steps outlined in installing an app like Redmine or Teambox, if you can get those installed you'll have a better understanding of what you have to do here.

Comment: This is the stuff I'm having a hard time understanding. I'll look into it though.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to point the virtualhost to the public directory, not the root path.

Second:I suggest you run rake assets:precompile on your local machine and load the public/assets folder to your host.

Third: look at the permissions on the files and folders you uploaded, the webserver should be able to read and execute them.

Forth: if the hosting is running apache as a webserver, you do need mod_passenger installed.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you haven't deployed a Rails project before, it's really NOT for the faint of heart, and not as simple as "installing apache" and starting it up — and you're REALLY in for a treat if you try getting it to run on OSX, which configures apache very weirdly (especially on Lion, eesh)

So.

1) Just don't bother running RoR on your Snow Leopard box over Apache, use the included rails server (rails s --debugger), you'll want the debugger available most of the time anyway.

2) Use a big end to end tutorial to get RoR running on your 1and1 box, preferably over Ubuntu (it's just easier) [Classic Slicehost Tutorial](http://articles.slicehost.com/2009/2/2/ubuntu-intrepid-mod_rails-installation)

3) Once you've completed #2, let us know how you've gotten on.

Comment: one problem is when you ssh to the 1and1 server
'sudo: command not found'

Comment: well, if it is a shared hosting sudo might not be accessible by regular users for safety.

Comment: not quite. If the bundle command is accessible by the user you can do like this `bundle install --gemfile /path/to/app/Gemfile --path /path/to/app/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test`

Comment: Is there a reason you MUST use 1and1?  There are lots of hosts out there nowadays that give you truly "bare" virtual machines where you have truly complete control and you'll never run into the issues like the one sudo one above.  Without trying to endorse one, a few examples include linode, rackspace, mediatemple, Amazon EC2, all of those are good choices.  Without complete control you're making this process more difficult than it needs to be.